# Exporting to KML using QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml

Background:

At 3.10.5, I have a Geopackage point layer that I wish to export as a KML, and then view in Google Earth.  The point layer has a single integer field, `id_unique`, that needs to display as a label in GE.

I use QGIS "Export > Save Feature As..." to create the KML.

Problem:

I am unable to export a .kml that displays the label from the *id_unique* field.  I have tried all combinations of options in the "Save Features As..." window.  When opened in the GE table of contents, the resulting points are always named `[no_name]`, and the map push-pins are not labeled, as shown below.

How do I export a KML that will display a field attribute as a GE label?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field named "Name", than your exported kml-file will show it as the name of the point and as label on the map besides the pin. Copy the values from the unique-id-field to the Name field, using the field calculator, which you can also use to create the field "Name":

[image]

Comment: Wow, who would have ever thought?  Well, maybe the [no-name] should have been a giveaway, but that never occurred to me.  I haven't seen *name* documented; do you know where you learned that?  Thanks!

Comment: I did not learn it, just a heuristic approch. I just went the other way: I created a named point in Google Earth, saved it as kml and opened that in QGIS to inspect how it looks. So it became clear that creating a file in the same manner should also work "backwards", going from QGIS to GE.

Comment: Well done, and a good lesson for me.